# how to fetch specific row from database using jquery in laravel and bind it textbox field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i want to fetch specific row data form database based on id using jquery ajax in laravel 5.4,but it does not work. no error from laravel framwork,

this my jquery part.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#batch').change(function(){
        var batch_id=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo route('selectbatch')?>",
            method:'post',
            data:{batch_id:batch_id},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#test").html(data.batch);
            }

        });

    });

});
```

and this is my controller part.

```
public function selectBatchinfo(Request $request)
{

    $bid=$request->input('batch_id');
    $batchinfo=DB::table('batches')->where('id',$bid)->pluck('s_amt');
    $data = view('register',compact('batches'))->render();
    return response()->json(['batch'=>$data]);

}
```

Comment: Instead of using `<?php echo ... ?>` use `"{{ route('selectbatch') }}"`

Comment: Change `$bid=$request->input('batch_id');` to  `$bid=$request->batch_id;`.

Comment: now it's shows the jquery error, (jquery.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/selectbatch 500 (Internal Server Error))

Comment: can you please show me an error photo

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/9oDMb0s.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code of your view similar to like this. pass token with post method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#batch').change(function(){
    var batch_id=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('selectbatch')}}",
        method:'post',
        data:{batch_id:batch_id,'_token':"{{csrf_token()}}"},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#test").html(data.batch);
        }

    });

});
});
```

in your controller

```
public function selectBatchinfo(Request $request)
{
    $bid=$request->batch_id;
    $batchinfo=DB::table('batches')->where('id',$bid)->pluck('s_amt');
    return $batchinfo;
}
```

in your route file

```
Route::post('selectbatch','YOUR_CONTROLLER@selectBatchinfo')->name('selectbatch');
```

try this it may work for you.